# what is the purpose of this device>

Tags: components, symbol

I have this device out of an old laptop, and I  have no idea what it is. there is a tiny tag that says something about RFID, and it has 4 wires going in. There is a coil of some sort, but most of the PCB is covered by foam. The original placement was adjacent to the touch pad mouse, and there was a symbol there shown in this picture:

[image]

here is the device, removed:
[image]

and the other side:
[image]

The laptop was a Dell Latitude E6500. When I went to Dell's site, but I couldn’t figure out what the purpose of this device is. Can anyone illuminate me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you rightly said that it has a tiny tag that says something about RFID. May be a contact-less smart card reader? You can you can login into your computer by both tapping a smart card to the icon and typing your password, offering added security.

Refer: [User Manual (English), Table 22: Contactless Smart Card](http://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1025084339.pdf)

Comment: I've never heard of such a device. I got this device as parts, rather than part of a complete laptop. Ive never seen the symbol before. So is there a card I would need to use this?

Comment: @joh: Yes, you will need to get a smart card, and configure your system to recognize it. Dell must have it documented. You may want to consult a Dell Service Centre to know more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Select Dell Latitude and Precision systems comes with an embedded contactless smart card reader. Out of the box, this reader is not PC/SC enabled. The contactless reader is only available through the CV chipset (Dell Credentials Vault), meaning that it will only work in PBA (Pre Boot Authentication), and when enrolling a contactless card through the Dell supported software (EmbassySuite/ControlPoint).

Read more from the link:
https://ridrix.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/how-to-enable-pcsc-support-for-dell-contactless-reader/